# I need to sum up the numbers between two and a cell's value, then multiply it by another value

Tags: google-sheets, math

I'm working on an RPG project, and want to get a preview of how costs will shake out.

The plan is for every raise of an attribute, you pay its new value times 9.

Going from 1 to 2 costs 18 XP.

If you wish to go from 1 to 4, you need to pay (2x9)+(3x9)+(4x9), or (9x9), 72.

I want to be able to punch in 9 for an attribute in my google sheet, and have it able get to the 44x9 needed to get the 396 cost to get that. Is there an easy way to do this I'm not seeing?

I looked at the Sum function, thinking I could set up an array (add all numbers between 2 and the value of the cell named Will) but the parsing doesn't work that way. I'm going all crosseyed, and feel that the answers either right in front of me, or is no.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

multiplies of 9 as array can be achieved like this:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(44)*9)
```

Answer (score 0):

For any current value to any new value:

```
=sum(sequence(new_value-current_value,1,(current_value+1)*9,9))
```